# In FlotCharts, how can I make the tooltips always visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, flot

As a newbee trying o study all of this, but just get pour information from ther friend google. Maybe I am doing the wrong question.

I **[folow this instructions in Stach Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261252/flotcarts-tooltips-unable-to-put-in-one-single-series)**, but no success,

Please teach-me if I am doing this wrong...

My graph is in real time, mimetizing one EGC, (a heart beat):

=> how to always show this "tooltips"(getRandomData3())? (not only when the mouse is over, but all the time)?

I realy apreciate any help ou tips. Thanks

here is my Data Series:

```
   function getRandomData3() { 
        if (data3.length > 0)
            data3 = data3.slice(1);

        while (data3.length < totalPoints) {
             if (flagGo==1){
                 instantFlag=200;
                 flagGo=2
             }
             else{
                instantFlag=1000;
             }

            instantShowFlag = instantFlag;
            data3.push(instantShowFlag);
        }

        // Zip the generated y values with the x values
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data3.length; ++i) {
            res.push([i, data3[i]])
        }
    //  console.log(data1);
        return res;
    }
```

and how I put it on the graphics

```
    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{data: getRandomData1()}, {data: getRandomData2()}, {data: getRandomData3()}], {
        series: {
            shadowSize: 0 // Drawing is faster without shadows
        },
        yaxis:  {
            min: -50,
            max: 250,
            color: "#EDC240",
        },
        xaxis:  {
            show: false,  
        },
        tooltip: {
            show: true,
            content: 'FLAG これはたとえばです',
            shifts: {
                x:  10,
                y: -10,
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            mouseActiveRadius: 30,
        }

    });

    function update() {

        plot.setData([{data: getRandomData1()}, {data: getRandomData2()}, {data: getRandomData3()}]);
        plot.draw();
        setTimeout(update, updateInterval);

    }
    update();
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure that's even an option

Comment: well...  I think there is not..  But I was able to find another solution. thanks for this help!

Comment: What kind of solution